# How is hyperledger composer playground implementing the "All Transactions"?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

When I try to use a query for "org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord" the results doesn't show the input for system transactions like AddAsset, AddParticipant, etc.
I want to create an audit trail for a single asset using queries.

There have been many questions about tracking the history of the asset, but I couldn't find a solution for this.

There must be a solution to this, hyperledger playground shows exactly how I would prefer in its "All Transaction" in the test section. So how can we code something to get same output as all transactions.

the query i used

```
query selectHistoricalRecord {
description: "Select all Historical Record of AddAsset"
statement:
    SELECT org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord
        WHERE (transactionType == 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddAsset')
}
```

the logic.js for this

```
/**
* Remove all high volume commodities
* @param {org.example.trading.GetAssetHistory} tx - the asset for constructing audit trail
* @transaction
*/
async function GetAssetHistory(tx) 
{
    let results = await query('selectHistoricalRecord');
    console.log( results );
}
```

the output is as:
[image: console log output]

but in all transaction:
we get something like this:
[image: all transactions]

My questions is how is this "all transactions" showing the input, but historian doesn't. What other way can i get input for system transactions.

Comment: you can use the events to record more detail about the transaction. when you query on historian record the events detail will be available under "eventsEmitted": parameter of response Object.

Comment: how do i add events to system transactions like "AddAsset"

Comment: plus it would be really helpful if we could know how all transaction does it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should get you the results:

> query a2 {
>   description: "Select Transaction"
>     statement:
>         SELECT org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddAsset
>   }

Comment: that works, I was actually looking for such a query in which we can specify "WHERE Id == 'xyz' ". Reason being its not scalable to get all the assets and trying to filter out the id from the logic.js file. Using couchdb if we can query for that specific id it will be very efficient. The purpose of forming a audit trail is proving to be difficult in a tool which was created to make it simple. I guess future builds will find a solutions.